# Spaces in variable assignments in shell scripts

Tags: shell, variable, assignment

What is the difference between below variables assignments?

```
var=23
var =23
var= 23
var = 23
```

Is there any difference in space around the assignment operator?

Comment: In most programming languages this would make no difference at all... Is there actually a difference to begin with? Also you're talking oldschool sh here? not ash/zsh/bash or other new things?

Comment: Only the first examples sets a variable.

Comment: Then don't the last 3 just throw a syntax error?  or do they actually hold meaning?

Comment: @Cestarian they can mean something, if you have a command called `var` then `var =23` would be pass `=23` to var, and `var = 23` would pass `=` and `23` to var. Or, if you have a command called `var=` then `var= 23` would pass `23` to the command `var=`.

Comment: @DisplayName Sounds like sh was replaced for a good reason in modern operating systems...

Comment: @Cestarian Replaced by `bash`, which does exactly the same thing as `sh` in all four cases.

Comment: @pfnuesel Oh, well I could have guessed. It makes sense since it needs to be usable for launching programs (although programs can often take arguments like =23 and = 23 the same way)

Comment: @DisplayName actually, you can't have `=` in a command name/function/alias, can't edit the comment but it would instead make $var empty and run the command 23.

Comment: @DisplayName Although you can't indeed with aliases and functions, you actually can have an `=` in a command name.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

That very much depends on the shell. If we only look at the 4 main shell families (Bourne, csh, rc, fish):

### Bourne family

That is the Bourne shell and all its variants and `ksh`, `bash`, `ash`/`dash`, `zsh`, `yash`.

- `var=23`: that's the correct scalar variable assignment syntax: a word that consists of unquoted letters, digits or underscores followed by an unquoted `=` that appears before a command argument (here it's on its own)
- `var =23`, the `var` command with `=23` as argument (except in `zsh` where `=something` is a special operator that expands to the path of the `something` command. Here, you'd likely to get an error as `23` is unlikely  to be a valid command name).
- `var= 23`: an assignment `var=` followed by a command name `23`. That's meant to execute `23` with `var=` passed to its environment (`var` environment variable with an empty value).
- `var = 23`, `var` command with `=` and `23` as argument. Try with `echo = 23` for instance.

`ksh`, `zsh`, `bash` and `yash` also support some forms of [*array* / *list* variables with variation in syntax](/q/238080) for both assignment and expansion. `ksh93`, `zsh` and `bash` also have support for *associative arrays* with again variation in syntax between the 3. `ksh93` also has *compound variables* and *types*, reminiscent of the objects and classes of object programming languages.

### Csh family

`csh` and `tcsh`. Variable assignments there are with the `set var = value` syntax for scalar variables, `set var = (a b)` for arrays, `setenv var value` for environment variables, `@ var=1+1` for assignment and arithmetic evaluation.

So:

- `var=23` is just invoking the `var=23` command.
- `var =23` is invoking the `var` command with `=23` as argument.
- `var= 23` is invoking the `var=` command with `23` as argument
- `var = 23` is invoking the `var` command with `=` and `23` as arguments.

### Rc family

That's `rc`, `es` and `akanga`. In those shells, variables are arrays and assignments are with `var = (foo bar)`, with `var = foo` being short for `var = (foo)` (an array with one `foo` element) and `var =` short for `var = ()` (array with no element, use `var = ''` or `var = ('')` for an array with one empty element).

In any case, blanks (space or tab) around `=` are allowed and optional. So in those shells those 4 commands are equivalent and equivalent to `var = (23)` to assign an array with one element being `23`.

### Fish

In `fish`, the variable assignment syntax is `set var value1 value2`. Like in `rc`, variables are arrays.

So the behaviour would be the same as with `csh`, except that `fish` won't let you run a command with a `=` in its name. If you have such a command, you need to invoke it via `sh` for instance: `sh -c 'exec weird===cmd'`.

So all `var=23` and `var= 23` will give you an error, `var =23` will call the `var` command with `=23` as argument and `var = 23` will call the `var` command with `=` and `23` as arguments.

Answer (score 14):

`var=23` assigns 23 to the variable `var`.

`var =23` tries to run command (or alias, or function) `var` with argument `=23`

`var = 23` ditto, but arguments `=` and `23`

`var= 23` sets `var` environment variable to blank string, then runs command `23`

Yes, shell is weird as a programming language. But it makes perfect sense as a *shell* for interactive use, where spaces separate commands and arguments. Most "special characters" (`=` in this case) have special meaning only in particular positions, to allow for almost arbitrary arguments to commands.See the above interpretations.

Answer (score 5):

- `var=23` is the correct syntax for assigning value to a variable.
- `var =23` is considered as command `var` with `=23` option/argument for command `var` (Though correct/standard syntax for argument/option is `-option` or `--option`)
- `var= 23` will assigns nothing to `var` as white-space breaks the process of assignment and `23` will be considered as another command. The workaround is `var=\ 23` or `var=' 23'` for storing white-space.
- `var = 23` has similar effect as discussed in 2<sup>nd</sup> case.

  Actually this type usage of space around `=` is usually used in testing condition inside `[[ ]]`. Example for Bash:

  ```
  string1 = string2
         True if the strings are equal.  = should be used with the test command  for  POSIX  conformance.  
         When used with the [[ command, this performs pattern matching as described above (Compound Commands).
  ```

And after-all the behaviour of white-space around `=` depends on your shell and the programming languages.