# bash string comparison failure, "command not found"

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to accomplish a multiple option text-based story, based on various user inputs. Though this seems like a fun project to test various statements, and begin scripting with the VI Editor. (Not trying to be super tech-savvy, nor am I experienced with scripting).

So here is what I got:

[image]

However; I can't get the last echo statement to produce results, as this is what comes up:

[image]

I tried using a '0' (digit) for the 'input_user_name', this way in the 'if' statement so it would be a number instead of a letter, but to no avail. Not really sure what's wrong (sigh). It's probably a super easy fix (I'm guessing).

Comment: Please remove your screenshots and re-add these as pasted text in a code block.  You can make a code block by selecting the block of text and pressing `CTRL`+`k`

Comment: Your screen shots are fine!

Comment: For many many good reasons, [please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text?cb=1)

Comment: @fpmurphy1 no they aren't, I can't copy and paste the code to my own system to debug for example

Comment: Sorry guys/gals. First post on the site, I though screen shots might help, but didn't take into consideration the code can't be copy/pasted.

Comment: Related: [Spaces in variable assignments in shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258727/spaces-in-variable-assignments-in-shell-scripts), but this one has another issue, too

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($input_user_name == 'n'); ...
```

The parenthesis are used for [command grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html#Command-Grouping), which isn't very useful in the `if` statement. (Unless you want a subshell for some reason.)
In practice, this is the same as `if $input_user_name == 'n';`, and that expands `input_user_name`, splits and globs the result, and runs it as a command. You entered `Bruce`, the shell runs the command `Bruce`.

Answer (score 0):

I made a few assumptions in this, but I have modified your code to the following:

```
#! /bin/bash -
clear
echo -e "\nWelcome, $(whoami)\nShall we change this to something more appropriate?"
read -rp "If not enter input 'n' and press [ENTER] " input_user_name

if [[ "$input_user_name" == 'n' ]]; then
        user_name="$(whoami)"
else
        user_name="$input_user_name"
fi

echo "You are ${user_name}!"
```

I've changed your first few `echo` lines into a single `echo -e` line which allows the use of special characters such as newline `\n`, tab `\t`, and some others.

I've also changed your `read` statement into a single line and added the `-r` switch which will prevent it from destroying any backslashes.

You were getting the error on line 10 because you were not doing a legitimate test.  You need to use brackets `[` or preferably `[[` instead of parenthesis.

Also in shell/bash syntax you cannot put a space in variable assignments that way.  It needs to be:

```
variable=value
```

NOT

```
variable = value
```

OR

```
$variable = value
```

etc

Comment: Sincerely thank you. This helps clarify some of the other previous 'echo' statements I've seen on other sites, as they included the -e switch too. Extremely new to all this so every bit of information, especially laid out with clarity, helps a ton!

Answer (score 0):

use square brackets [ ] instead of ( )

```
#!/bin/bash
set +x


clear
echo
echo "Welcome, $(whoami)"
echo

echo "Shall we change this to something more appropriate?"
echo "if no,simply enter 'n' then press [Enter]:"
read input_user_name

if [ $input_user_name == "n" ];
then user_name=`whoami`   ## i have used `` to get the value of whoami
else

user_name=$input_user_name
fi

echo "Your $user_name !"
```

output :

```
Welcome, vikasven

Shall we change this to something more appropriate?
if no,simply enter 'n' then press [Enter]:
Vikas
Your Vikas !
```

Answer (score -3):

Change `then user_name = $whoami` to `then user_name=$(whoami)`

Comment: This still wouldn't work.  It would need to be: `user_name=$(whoami)` but should be: `user_name="$(whoami)"`

Comment: Oh why?  In the OP's example, `whoami` returns `bdraper`, i.e. effective userid.  No spaces in that string.  Assigning a string without spaces and double quotes have been perfectly valid in shells since the earliest Unix shell.

Comment: No they haven't and no it doesn't...they have been perfectly valid in shells that begin with the word "power".  In OP's example `echo "Welcome, $(whoami)"` works fine as it should.  None of his variable assignments work except for the read statement.

Comment: @Jesse_b. Strange, `user_name=$(whoami); echo $user_name`  works perfectly well for me and returns the expected result.

Comment: That isn't strange. That is exactly what I had suggested in my first comment.  Except now you are introducing security and functionality issues by not double quoting it...

Comment: I get the feeling you don't really care but in case you wanted to read up on it:  https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086

Comment: @Jesse_b I am afraid you are mistaken :) Word-slitting is **NOT** done when assigning to a variable. So this: `var=$(some cmd)` or `var=$other_var` is absolutely fine. However, in mere expansion, for example: `echo "$var"`, quotes are necessary, of course.

Comment: @Jesse_b If you are skeptical about this, I will quote bash manual for you: *"The text after the ‘=’ in each variable assignment undergoes tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal before being assigned to the variable."* - no word-splitting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37932117/8239155
Honestly with the whoami command it probably wouldn't be an issue but I'm sure someone can find a way to make a malicious username or something, so no, unless you have a good reason to not quote, you should in fact quote.

Comment: @Jesse_b Yes, indeed, you proved my point. I just wanted to point out, even though this answer does not answer the problem whatsoever, that user_name=$(whoami) does not create, quoting your comment, *security and functionality issues*.

Comment: @Jesse_b Did you read the answer you posted? *Variable assignment creates a “double quote context”*. I will say it once more. You do not need quotes when assigning to a variable. `var=$(cmd)` is basically treated as if it were quoted like this: `var="$(cmd)"`.

Comment: Did you read it?  What about dash?  or the several other caveats that probably would never be an issue but still make this argument pointless...just quote it period

Comment: @Jesse_b And is OP using `dash`? No. He is in fact using `bash`. You should use features available in the shell you are using. It's like saying: never use `[[ ]]` because it does not exist in `sh`!!! You see my point? Don't tell someone something is incorrect when it is not.

Comment: You can do whatever you want.  I will recommend to OP that, especially as someone new to scripting, he always quote any command substitution unless he has a reason not to, and understands that reason.

Comment: @Jesse_b And you still don't get what I am trying to say. It's a fine recommendation, quote if you like, I myself think it is better, more foolproof. But don't tell someone it is incorrect when unquoted. You are presenting false information to them.