# Error while using array in AIX : syntax error error at line 81 : '(' unexpected

Tags: ksh, aix, array

I am trying to execute one .sh script in AIX environment, but it's giving an error at below line

```
tableList = ( Value1 Value2 Value3 )
```

I have tried executing the script like below:

1. `sh file1.ksh`
2. I renamed the file to `.ksh` then executed the file `sh ./file1.sh`

Comment: there are no such things as file extensions in Unix: it is just part of the file name. To make it use a different shell you need to run it with a different shell. A cool way to do this is with a `#!` as the first line of the script. e.g. `#!/bin/sh`, `#!/bin/ksh` or `#!/bin/bash`. Then make the file executable.

Comment: See also: [Spaces in variable assignments in shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258727/spaces-in-variable-assignments-in-shell-scripts). This is also one of those cases where the error message might actually point in the direction of at least the immediate problem.

Answer (score 3):

The `sh` shell don't generally understand arrays as they are not part of the POSIX standard.  The filename of the script is arbitrary, so a `.sh` or a `.ksh` filename suffix means nothing whatsoever.

Also, your array assignment syntax is a bit wrong (too many spaces).  Corrected, it would look like

```bash
tableList=( Value1 Value2 Value3 )
```

Note the lack of blanks between the end of the variable's name and the `(`.

To be able to run your script, you would need to execute it with a shell that implements arrays, such as `ksh93`, `bash`, `zsh`, or `yash` (depending what other shell constructs you are using).  Note that `ksh` on AIX is `ksh88` which has a slightly different syntax for assigning values to arrays (it uses `set -A tableList Value1 Value2 Value3`).

The best way of running your script with `ksh93` is to add a `#!`-line to the top of the script, pointing to the `ksh93` interpreter, and then make the script executable with `chmod +x scriptname`.

To use the `ksh93` shell on AIX, the very first line of the script should look like

```sh
#!/usr/bin/ksh93
```

After that, don't specify an explicit interpreter on the command line when you run the script:

```
./scriptname
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR, AIX uses a ksh88 based POSIX shell as /bin/sh

ksh88 does not support

```
tableList=( Value1 Value2 Value3 )
```

and this is not required by POSIX.

Comment: Hi, I have mentioned  #!/usr/bin/env bash on the top of script.