# shell programming syntax error

Tags: shell, syntax

```
num1 = 20
num2 = 20

echo $(( num1 + num2 ))
echo $(( num1 - num2 ))
echo $(( num1 * num2 ))
echo $(( num1 / num2 ))
echo $(( num1 % num2 ))
```

Error :

```
./practice.sh: line 53: num1: command not found
./practice.sh: line 54: num2: command not found
0
0
0
./practice.sh: line 59: num1 / num2 : division by 0 (error token is "num2 ")
./practice.sh: line 60: num1 % num2 : division by 0 (error token is "num2 ")
```

What am I missing? When I tried some number instead of `num1` and `num2` inside echo. I notice that it was printing correctly.. But, What is happening right here..?

Comment: Typo: There can be no spaces around `=` in an assignment.

Comment: There should be no spaces either side of `=` on the first 2 lines.

Comment: See also [Spaces in variable assignments in shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/258727)

Comment: I wonder why this is off-topic? The fact that the question's title contains the word "programming" doesn't mean that it's a programming question.

Comment: @berndbausch It's off topic because it's a typo. "Questions describing a problem that can't be reproduced and seemingly went away on its own (or went away when a typo was fixed) are off-topic as they are unlikely to help future readers."  If you wish, I could reopen it and immediately close it as a duplicate of the question in my previous comment.

Comment: @Kusalananda I agree that this is certainly not the first time the question was asked, and it is indeed a duplicate, but reopening would be a bit too much. Sorry for making you waste your time, but on the other hand I learned something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
num1=20
num2=20
```

When I tried with removing spaces from num1 and num2. I notice it's working

Comment: Downloading from `shellcheck.net` is an excellent investment in your future. In this case, it says: `SC1068: Don't put spaces around the = in assignments.`